# How to get transaction hash in a geth tracer?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to build a custom tracer, similar to [these](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/eth/tracers/internal/tracers). To be specific, I am trying to add transaction hash info to [call_tracer.js](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/tracers/internal/tracers/call_tracer.js).

I have tried looking at Go code which [initializes the tracers](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/tracers/tracer.go) and checking every possible function call or property I could find, but I was unable to get the current transaction ID. Is this information even available to the tracer?

I am running code like this:

```
$ nc -U /opt/geth1.8/geth.ipc
{"id": 1, "method": "debug_subscribe", "params": ["traceChain", "0x6714a", "0x6714b", {"tracer": "{ step: function(log, db) {}, fault: function(log, db) {}, result: function(ctx, db) { return {ctx: ctx}; }, }"}]}
```

Tracer is an object which defines 3 functions, `step`, `fault` and `result` - my question is, how do I get current transaction hash in either `step()` or `result()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are currently not available. It's something we'd like to add however.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I couldn't find it. It's a shame though, it could really help export all internal transactions, but without hash I can't use it in my case. Would it make sense to open an issue for this?

Answer (score 2):

If it helps someone: as @Péter Szilágyi said, it seems one can't get transaction hash directly from the tracer.

But - it can still be obtained via regular JSON RPC. So if you're after internal transactions, you can get them via tracer (use supplied `call_tracer` for instance) and fetch transaction hashes via JSON RPC call `eth_getBlockByNumber` (with second param set to true). Note that JSON RPC will give you the transactions in the block in the same order (which is order of execution).

Not ideal, but looks like it's still much faster than calling `debug_traceTransaction`.