# How to get internal transactions from call_tracer results in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to export internal transactions from Ethereum network via [geth tracers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/40285/23064). For that, I think [call_tracer](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/tracers/internal/tracers/call_tracer.js) would be a suitable candidate. However, I am having trouble interpreting its output and would appreciate some help.

For instance, in [block 50117](https://etherscan.io/block/50117) there is a [transaction 0x1072369c82...4617](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1072369c82285007f94f5f97a8df8b680e9939c321d617f4d4012fdf8f0f4617) which has [1 internal transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1072369c82285007f94f5f97a8df8b680e9939c321d617f4d4012fdf8f0f4617#internal). `call_tracer` returns this:

```
{
    'from': '0x834e9b529ac9fa63b39a06f8d8c9b0d6791fa5df',
    'gas': '0x2be92',
    'gasUsed': '0x10912',
    'input': '0x',
    'output': '0x',
    'time': '2.843415ms',
    'to': '0x109c4f2ccc82c4d77bde15f306707320294aea3f',
    'type': 'CALL',
    'value': '0xde0b6b3a7640000',
    'calls': [
        {
            'from': '0x109c4f2ccc82c4d77bde15f306707320294aea3f',
            'input': '0x',
            'to': '0x881b0a4e9c55d08e31d8d3c022144d75a454211c',
            'type': 'CALL',
            'value': '0xde0b6b3a7640000'
        }
    ]
}
```

However in a block [700000](https://etherscan.io/txs?block=700000) there is transaction [0x1a0e7e095...6d3e](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1a0e7e095b84ebae5b3576b5e4b2e80889d4e84138484fb5c83a46c4beab6d3e). According to Etherscan, it has no internal transactions, but it does have [4 events](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1a0e7e095b84ebae5b3576b5e4b2e80889d4e84138484fb5c83a46c4beab6d3e#eventlog). `call_tracer` tells this about it:

```
{
    'from': '0xbb96fed30742eadedb9f0578876c8871edc7bfe8',
    'gas': '0x33738',
    'gasUsed': '0x22af2',
    'input': '0x3ed48679000000000000000000000000f6869286c14193f97292d7e3aa9c086deaba7c4b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005671377e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001a0000000000000000000000000e8b61ccea39114f2d589272d5ad24ebabcf34df8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a7d8c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000660d15e1338e132128dfcdf95bf90d16218e113f970b3f44545bf2a2ee8a491264a8218e2fec5a37375530cebdf2eff9a3575b6aae57c5af7f48de98f45c6e934ca4fb9f6130e9ea2ead7edfb8774f6a8158cef03a706772ac470da0fdf2a698d77fb9ed1df3be4cdecc2235831394370f19fc1b2ee88779fe7910397ee2fa54fdb07137559c37c3e4ad47ed53be9023d1e60f06306e3438ca993d3a72d7f2e7f6333c56fceb646f95e9285e021aea5c7f4c7a2c4c023225289b373cba8fd39f40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b',
    'output': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    'time': '73.293893ms',
    'to': '0x7de5aba7de728950c92c57d08e20d4077161f12f',
    'type': 'CALL',
    'value': '0x1',
    'calls': [
        {
            'from': '0x7de5aba7de728950c92c57d08e20d4077161f12f',
            'gas': '0x256db',
            'gasUsed': '0x1abbe',
            'input': '0xbeabacc8000000000000000000000000f6869286c14193f97292d7e3aa9c086deaba7c4b000000000000000000000000e8b61ccea39114f2d589272d5ad24ebabcf34df8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a7d8c00',
            'output': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
            'to': '0x1158c3c9a70e85d8358972810ed984c8e6ffcf0f',
            'type': 'CALL',
            'value': '0x0',
            'calls': [
                {
                    'from': '0x1158c3c9a70e85d8358972810ed984c8e6ffcf0f',
                    'gas': '0x1eefc',
                    'gasUsed': '0x1df',
                    'input': '0xf8b2cb4f000000000000000000000000f6869286c14193f97292d7e3aa9c086deaba7c4b',
                    'output': '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006164dc58',
                    'to': '0x276c5c6ca8507ed7bac085fc9b9521f4f54b58d3',
                    'type': 'CALL',
                    'value': '0x0'
                },
                {
                    'from': '0x1158c3c9a70e85d8358972810ed984c8e6ffcf0f',
                    'gas': '0x1ebaa',
                    'gasUsed': '0x3a53',
                    'input': '0x07bc6fad000000000000000000000000f6869286c14193f97292d7e3aa9c086deaba7c4b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a7d8c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
                    'output': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
                    'to': '0x276c5c6ca8507ed7bac085fc9b9521f4f54b58d3',
                    'type': 'CALL',
                    'value': '0x0',
                    'calls': [
                        {
                            'from': '0x276c5c6ca8507ed7bac085fc9b9521f4f54b58d3',
                            'input': '0x',
                            'to': '0x1158c3c9a70e85d8358972810ed984c8e6ffcf0f',
                            'type': 'CALL',
                            'value': '0xa7d8c00'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'from': '0x1158c3c9a70e85d8358972810ed984c8e6ffcf0f',
                    'gas': '0x1aee9',
                    'gasUsed': '0x1f7c',
                    'input': '0xec2ac54e000000000000000000000000e8b61ccea39114f2d589272d5ad24ebabcf34df8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a7d8c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
                    'output': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
                    'to': '0x276c5c6ca8507ed7bac085fc9b9521f4f54b58d3',
                    'type': 'CALL',
                    'value': '0x0'
                },
                {
                    'from': '0x1158c3c9a70e85d8358972810ed984c8e6ffcf0f',
                    'gas': '0x1856e',
                    'gasUsed': '0x1f7c',
                    'input': '0xec2ac54e00000000000000000000000048175da4c20313bcb6b62d74937d3ff985885701000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
                    'output': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
                    'to': '0x276c5c6ca8507ed7bac085fc9b9521f4f54b58d3',
                    'type': 'CALL',
                    'value': '0x0'
                },
                {
                    'from': '0x1158c3c9a70e85d8358972810ed984c8e6ffcf0f',
                    'gas': '0x14cf4',
                    'gasUsed': '0x1df',
                    'input': '0xf8b2cb4f000000000000000000000000f6869286c14193f97292d7e3aa9c086deaba7c4b',
                    'output': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056e75058',
                    'to': '0x276c5c6ca8507ed7bac085fc9b9521f4f54b58d3',
                    'type': 'CALL',
                    'value': '0x0'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that number of calls is larger than 4 and that they are nested.

Is there some way I can distinguish internal transactions from any other call (event,...)? That is, I am interested in all ways that ETH value is transferred between addresses, and nothing else. Can this be done?

**EDIT:** as @Ismael pointed out, Etherscan results for block [700000](https://etherscan.io/txs?block=700000) are probably invalid - both Geth and Parity return no events for this block and their traces both return multiple internal calls.

However it seems that either Geth's or Parity's handling of value is invalid somehow. Parity's `CALL`s all have value 0, while one of Geth's `CALL`s has a value of `0xa7d8c00` (this can be see both in above output and in a call to `debug_traceTranscation`). Does anyone know where the discrepancy comes from?

Comment: Have you considered it may be a bug in etherscan? Geth vm trace fails and parity trace show several calls.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that! My geth (v1.8.0) returned the results, but there is still mismatch in values between Parity and Geth (or, more likely, I am interpreting the results incorrectly). I have updated the question, if you have any idea, I would appreciate it...